# Splitting a python list with common end points

Tags: python

Suppose I have a python list as: `points_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,1]`

And I need to split this list containing the number of elements in the `index_list=[2, 2, 6, 3]` But having **common endpoints**

That is:

- First **2** elements from `points_list` : `[1,2]`
- Next **2** elements from the `points_list` but it should start from the place it stopped before : `[2,3]`
- Then the next **6** elements : `[3,4,5,6,7,8]`
- Finally, **3** elements in the same way : `[8,9,1]`

Ultimately, what I expect is to have something like: `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4,5,6,7,8],[8,9,1]]` which corresponds to the number of elements mentioned in the `index_list=[2, 2, 6, 3]`

Can you please help me to perform this task

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: @azro I apologize. But I did spend quite a lot of time thinking about this problem and the internet searches, only gave splitting of lists without a common end point. So, if possible, please reopen this question because it will be helpful to others as well.

Comment: Always share your tries, even if they fail, that is in fact the goal of that website : fix YOUR code, rather than code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code:

```
points_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,1]
index_list=[2, 2, 6, 3]
res = []
end_point = 0
for i in index_list:
    temp_list = points_list[end_point:end_point+i] # Get the list
    res.append(temp_list) # Append it
    end_point = points_list.index(temp_list[-1]) # Get the index of the last value
print(res)
```

Support for repeating numbers (thanks to azro and S.B):

```
points_list = [3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 8, 9, 1]
index_list=[2, 2, 6, 3]
res = []
for i in index_list:
    res.append(points_list[:i]) # Append it
    points_list = points_list[i-1:] # Reconfigure list
print(res)
```

Comment: Slicing is costly. You already have `temp_list`, why didn't you use `temp_list` in  `res.append` ?

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. I forgot to change that. EEEE

Comment: Oh one more thing, this doesn't give the correct result. `.index()` will hand  you only first occurrence. Test it with `points_list = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]`

Comment: The solution doesn't work if you have non unique values at the at an end point position. Try with `[3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 8, 9, 1], [2, 2, 6, 3]`